# Dropdown Materialize atributos data

Tags: materialize

Estou utilizando o materialize em um projeto e ao criar um menu com dropdown não consigo utilizar as opções disponíveis na documentação do materialize para personalizar o dropdown.

Opções como: 
data-hover="true" 
data-beloworigin="true" 
data-cosntrainwidth="false"

Ainda sim o dropdown não é exibido ao passar o mouse e continua abrindo em cima do item clicado.

O código do item do menu configurado com o dropdown é o seguinte:

```
`<li>
   <a class="dropdown-trigger" data-target="dropdown1" data-activates="dropdown1" data-hover="true" data-beloworigin="true" data-cosntrainwidth="false"> Prefeitura
     <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
   </a>
</li>`
```

Se souberem me ajudar por favor a entender porque essas opções do data não funcionam.

Comment: Poderia postar o teu código?

Comment: Cara o primeiro passo para vc conseguir uma resposta que te atenda é editar a pergunta e incluir o código HTML / CSS e JS que estiver usando. Sem isso não da para te responder. E diga qual versão do Materialize vc está usando!

Comment: Versão v1.0.0 materialize

Answer (score 0):

Cara vc está usando as propriedades da forma errada acredito. A customização deve ser feita com atributos no script do componente como no exemplo abaixo.

```
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({ suas opções aqui });
```

Vc pode consultar a documentação oficial que vc vai ver quais opções vc pode usar. `constrainWidth` `coverTrigger` e `hover` https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Repare que agora ao fazer o `hover` o `dropdown` já aparece abaixo...

```js
$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown({ 
  hover: true,
  inDuration: 1500,
  coverTrigger: false,
  constrainWidth: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  
  <a class='dropdown-trigger btn' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'>Meu Dropdown</a>


  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado. O problema mesmo era a versão do JQuery